# Difficulty installing cx_Freeze for Python 3.3

Tags: python, windows-installer

I'm trying to install cx_Freeze for Windows 64bit and Python 3.3, but when I get to this  page in the Windows installer, it can't find my Python and if I type in the directory it's intalled in it can't find it. You can see the snapshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kAJF.png).

What might the cause of my problem be?

Comment: Have you definitely got the right installer? It needs to match the Python interpreter, so even if you have 64-bit Windows you might need the 32-bit installer if you have 32-bit Python.

Comment: @Thomas K That's it! Thanks very much, I'm new to Stack Overflow but is there some way to give you rep for solving this?

Comment: I've reposted my comment as an answer. If you click the tick by it, the question will show up as solved and I get a few reputation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-posting as an answer:

Have you definitely got the right installer? It needs to match the Python interpreter, so even if you have 64-bit Windows you might need the 32-bit installer if you have 32-bit Python.